# Traveling across Europe as a minor

Tags: international-travel, minors

I am a US citizen and want to travel across Europe by myself after graduation, but I wont be 18 yet. Would I have a problem traveling through countries? Is there anything specific I would need from my parents, like a note? Are there places I can stay that I can book by myself, like youth hostels? I want to take the eurorail the whole way, would traveling by myself be a problem?

Comment: I can only offer my own experience so won't leave this as an answer. But I didn't have any problems. Some (very few) hotels didn't allow us to stay but all the hostels did, make sure to check and book in advance. You can't stay in an Airbnb unless 1 member of your party is over 18. The only problem we came across was spending money while on our trip, no one in our group had debit or credit cards when we went and none of us could get one. Our parents got Caxton pre-paid cards with suplimentary cards in our own names. I went with some friends (all under 18) but don't think it made a difference.

Comment: It would not do any harm to have a note signed by both parents ideally including a photocopy of their ID if they have any small enough (driving licence?). I say both parents in case anyone suspects you are being taken away from the jurisidiction of one parent.The site https://www.seat61.com is a wealth of information about train travel.

Comment: Whether hostels allow you to stay, at all or only with parental permission, depend on country rules, or national hosteling organization rules. Check them out before you assume you will be fine in all hostels. (Private hostels have different rules again and might be more or less strict.)